# Encoding values using base64_encode() together with implode

Tags: php

so I'm making an application in which a user selects multiple values from a select box and submits those values. At the backend, these values need to be used in the URL in the decoded form.
So suppose, if the values are :-

```
Business
Study
Finance
```

So instead of sending it like file.php?cat=Business|Study|Finance, I want these all categories encoded using (base64_encode) and then separated by the delimiter **|**.

I wrote this, but this doesn't solve my issue.

```
file.php?cat=<?php echo base64_encode(implode("|", $cat)); ?>
```

Where $cat is the array in which I receive the selections from the select box.
What should I do to make it work like I want ?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What isn't working here? Except that you implode values with . while you wanted with |

Comment: The values are not separated with the delimiter.

Comment: Well, first you have to decode your string from $_GET, and then explode by |. Rather than sending something like this x|y|z send xyz. Unless you have good reason to do so.

Comment: Your code does not match what you said you wanted. Your code base64 encodes the categories **after** you have concatenated them with the separator. Your text says that the you want the categories to be encoded **first** then the separator added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$encodedCats = array();

foreach($cat AS $val){
  $encodedCats[] = base64_encode($val);
}

?>

file.php?cat=<?php echo implode("|", $encodedCats); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php $arr = array('Business','Study','Finance');?>
<a href="clone.php?cat=<?php echo base64_encode(implode("|", $arr)); ?>">click</a>
```

For get values

```
$decode = base64_decode($_GET['cat']);
$arr = explode('|', $decode);
print_r($arr); //Array ( [0] => Business [1] => Study [2] => Finance )
```